# битрикс мета теги, как правильно добавить?

Tags: битрикс

следуя мануалу https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=35&LESSON_ID=1929 добавляю новые поля в: админка -> настройки -> настройки модулей -> управление структурой, вижу добавленное поле в свойствах страницы, прописываю ему значение и ничего, вывожу массив `$APPLICATION->GetPagePropertyList();` там параметры есть, что не так?

```
$APPLICATION->ShowMeta("sss", "ttt");

$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("my_add", "я добавил");
$APPLICATION->ShowMeta("my_add");

$r = $APPLICATION->GetPagePropertyList();
print_r($r);//my_add есть в массиве
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мета-теги в шаблоне могут выводиться как все сразу:

```
<?$APPLICATION->ShowMeta();?>
```

Так и по одному:

```
<?$APPLICATION->ShowMeta("keywords");?>
<?$APPLICATION->ShowMeta("description");?>
```

Проверьте, что ваше новое свойство страницы действительно выводится в шаблоне. [Мануал](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=3429&LESSON_PATH=3913.4564.4930.3428.3429).

Comment: ```$APPLICATION->ShowMeta();``` выдаёт: "[ArgumentCountError] 
Too few arguments to function CAllMain::ShowMeta(), 0 passed in..." также в документации я не увидел вызова без передачи аргументов. Также я пробовал прописывать в категории (.section.php). Страница реагирует только на модификацию дефолтных тегов

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста: проблема с выводом свойства или с его заполнением?

Comment: с выводом, т.е. ничего не выводит на страницу, я добавил в вопрос код, который не работает. Кеш обновлял, смотрю в инструментах разработчика, пытался через файлы, через админку.

Comment: А "my_add" нигде не очищается/перебивается дальше по коду страницы? ShowMeta - одна из отложенных функций, её результат будет выведен только после формирования всей страницы. Т.е. на него можно повлиять в любом месте.

Comment: нет, я разные варианты пробовал, может что-то с сайтом. Можете подсказать SetPageProperty может вывести тайтл, а может вывести мета, т.к. это зарегистрированные ключи в самом битриксе он понимает, в какой тег обернуть тайтл, а в какой дескрипшин, но как битрикс выводит произвольные поля (которые я не могу вывести), в какие теги он их заворачивает?

Comment: SetPageProperty не выводит свойства, а устанавливает их. Выводит свойства, как мета-теги, функция `CMain::ShowMeta(ID_свойства, атрибут_name_тэга, стандарт_оформления_мета_тега)`. По умолчанию ID_свойства = атрибут_name_тэга. Значение свойства будет вписано в атрибут **content**. Вот [тут](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cmain/showmeta.php) об этом очень понятно. Ну и эта функция оборачивает свойства в тег **meta**. Для вывода **title** обычно используется `ShowTitile()`.

Comment: да, я разобрался с этим. Но в целом я не могу понять логику: 1) контент менеджер добавляет новое поле и для страницы заполняет его значение, но его нигде нет, надо в файле прописывать вывод?! контент менеджеру? 2) ожидаешь вывод в хидере, зря - это бред какой то мета в боди

Comment: Прошу прощения, `ShowTitle()`, конечно же, опечатался в сообщении выше. Так вам удалось вывести ваше свойство? Логика: 1) Тут на всё воля разработчиков шаблона и сайта. Можно написать код шаблона так, чтобы он выводил все свойства страницы/раздела в качестве мета-тегов (используя тот же `GetPagePropertyList()`). Другой вариант (если я не ошибаюсь): можно запретить контент-менеджеру добавлять новые свойства, а оставить только заполнение старых (ИМХО, это более правильный вариант). 2) Переместите вывод свойств из тела страницы в файл header.php вашего шаблона

Comment: да, теги были в body оказывается, в хидере также работает, спасибо :) А ещё последний вопрос: в свойствах страницы пишут не только мета теги, а что-то ещё? вариант с закрытием - будут дёргать программиста, может вариант c приставками, т.е. мета будет "meta_тут ключ" или на практике это не работает и контент менеджеры всё путают?

Comment: Иногда в свойства страницы пишут не только мета-теги, но и другие данные. Частый пример: заголовок H1. Тут всё зависит от необходимого функционала и выдумки разработчика сайта. В вашем случае сразу возникает вопрос: а зачем вам произвольные мета-теги? Нельзя обойтись фиксированным набором?

Comment: для Н1 есть отдельное поле. Смотрите, новое свойство - это ключ -> значение, т.е. не произвольная строка, а в битриксе кроме ShowMeta какие есть аналогичные функции, которые можно применить именно к этим свойствам страницы? Логика у меня простая: 1) я закрываю доп. поля - меня дёргают и просят добавить например ```<meta name = "twitter: card" content = "summary">``` 2) можно сразу все варианты мета туда включить, но завтра появится новый и меня опять будут дёргать. Поэтому если в полях может быть только значение для MetaShow я все вывожу в цикле и всё, а если нет, надо думать.

Comment: вот к стати https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/1978404

Comment: Ну если так смотреть, тогда вам могут понадобиться мета-теги с атрибутами property или http-equiv, например. ShowMeta уже так не умеет. И тут вам придётся использовать функцию GetProperty и самому оборачивать её ответ в тег. Или использовать что-то готовое, [например](https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/dev2fun.opengraph/). Вообще, для вашей задачи свойства страницы - недостаточный инструмент, слишком простой. Попробуйте на Маркетплэйсе поискать кастомный модуль.

Comment: получилось такое решение: добавили новое поле, написали условно "og:keyboard" и т.д. - это будет ```<мета name..``` если в поле добавить весь тег целиком, то он и выведется целиком. Условия можно добавить, например если ссылка и т.д. Работает это так: в ini.php событие onEpilog, в нём я в цикле прохожу массив и по условию либо обенуть в тег, либо вывести как строка. Нормально ли такое решение? Будет ли работать кеш страницы? как вам такой вариант?

Comment: Ну вполне годное решение, раз оно у вас заработало. На кэш страницы это повлиять никак не должно. Только не совсем ясна логика выбора события onEpilog в качестве момента обработки. Т.к. мета-теги выводятся в header, логичнее было бы использовать события OnBeforeProlog или OnProlog.

Comment: я посмотрю эти события, спасибо. Для вывода в хидере я использую  ```$APPLICATION->AddHeadString($str);``` правда пока выводятся дубли, возможно предложенные вами события это решат, если нет, то была идея получить буфер и заменить в нём, но не нашёл есть ли к нему доступ, также можно модифицировать страницу по моему. Я могу с вами получить связь помимо этого сайта? У меня проблема в том, что изучение без подсказок идёт медленно (такая уж дока у битрикса), а для участия в проекте надо знать битрикс, в общем замкнутый круг. Вы мне совет и я вам может чем смогу помочь

Comment: Я уже почти год ничего под Битрикс не программировал. Пишите в чат (судя по рейтингу у вас должна быть эта привилегия) - помогу, чем смогу. На счёт документации вы очень зря: она у Битрикса очень подробная. Правда разрозненная по множеству источников: курсы, документация, другая документация, старая, новая и т.д. и т.п. Ещё в наличии очень живое сообщество - на Битрикс-форуме можно найти кучу полезной инфы.

Comment: основная проблема - это понять его логику архитектурную, ну как с языком, я не знаю си, но я точно знаю, что у него есть: функции для работы с массивами, строками и т.д. Это ведь не загуглишь, а битрикс, помимо раскиданных доков чудит ещё и описанием, если бы они нормально писали доки я бы не создавал этот вопрос, в вопросе есть ссылка - где там про то, что внесённые новые поля никак нигде не отобразятся или что вывод будет в теле страницы и т.д. Чат только отсюда можно создать? в профиле не увидел

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102888/